# Rewrite history to remove all additions of lines matching a certain pattern

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a range of commits in a C++ codebase. I added a particular include in a set of files that I want to undo for the whole range of commits. Is there any way of automatically going through the list of commits, and for each commit, remove all lines in any of the hunks that match say `+#include <i_regret_adding_this>`, i.e if the line adds `#include <i_regret_adding_this>`?

I've considered using for instance `git format-patch` and `git am`, but just removing such lines in the unified diffs corrupt them. So far I haven't really found any good solution.

Comment: `git rebase --exec <a command to remove line>` and the command could be something like `sed -i '/#include <i_regret_adding_this>/d' file1 file2…`

Comment: @phd Thank you, but that doesn't exactly do what I want, because it will also remove pre-existing identical lines. And in my particular case that's a problem that's not easy to work around, even if I only limit myself to the files changed in the commit.

Comment: Alas, there is no simple way. With `git revert` you can undo all commits completely, but to find out what lines were added you need to parse `git diff`.

Comment: About how many files have the problem? Across about how many commits were the mistakes introduced? Is the branch linear during and after the commits you wish to rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky... but might work.

In below example I ran from HEAD~0 till HEAD~2.
(replace git ls-files with the list of the files you want to change)

Outer loop runs over commits you want to do the change in.
Inner loop runs over files.
With git blame you mark all lines with their commit IDs, then check if commit ID matches commit ID from loop - if match then delete pattern.
After this delete all git blames patterns  (probably this part can be improved... could get false positives) and overwrite file with this output.

```
for i in {0..2}; do for file in $(git ls-files); do git blame $file | sed -e "/$(git rev-parse --short HEAD~$i).*#include <i_regret_adding_this>/d" -e 's#[0-9].*(*.) ##g' > $file; done; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the adjustment in stages so adjusting hunk headers doesn't get necessary: do the format-patch, change the additions of that include into the addition of a *marked* include, am the result, then do a filter-branch / filter-repo to remove all the marked includes.

Comment: Are you saying that I should essentially search-and-replace in the patch files, replacing the unwanted  addition with an addition of some unique string? And then run the patches, and finally end by doing an exec rebase removing the unique string at each commit? That sounds like it would work! Thank you!